# Second fundamental form of Hypersurfaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Consider a parametrization of a hypersurface $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $x: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.
It is known that the Second Fundamental Form at a point $p=x(u)$ is given by
$$ II_p(w)= w^T(h_{ij})w,$$

$$ h_{ij}=\langle N(u),x_{u_iu_j}(u)\rangle.$$

When we have a manifold $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n+r}$ of codimention $r$, the Second Fundamental Form is defined by
$$ II_p: T_pM \longrightarrow N_pM$$
$$II_p(w(p))=B(w,w)(p),$$
for $w \in \mathcal{X}(U)$, that is $w $ is a vector field on $M$. Considering $\mathcal{N}(U)$ the set of normal vector fields, the map $B$ is given by
$$B: \mathcal{X}(U)\times\mathcal{X}(U) \longrightarrow \mathcal{N}(U) 
$$
$$B(w_1,w_2)= {\nabla}_{\overline{w}_1}\overline{w}_2 - ({\nabla}_{\overline{w}_1}\overline{w}_2)^T $$

Here, the bars indicates that we are taking extensions of $w_1,w_2$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+r}$, and the superscrip T indicates the tangent component of the vector field.
My questions are: 1. How this extension mentioned is done ?
2. From the general definition, how can I get the definition for the case of codimention 1 ?

Comment: If each normal space has dimension $1$ and you have a unit normal field $N$, then $II_p(w)$ is a scalar multiple of $N$. This scalar multiple is identified with $II_p(w)$ (and denoted by the same symbol). There's an identification $(T_pM)^\perp \cong \Bbb R$ going on here.